# WPF Cannot override Button conent foreground

Tags: wpf, button, resources, styles

I'm having trouble getting my MVVM View's button foreground to override the default style that I have set for TextBlock in App.xaml.

I have a TextBlock style set in App.xaml that defaults foreground for a TextBlock to Gainsboro as follows:

--In App.xaml

```
<!-- Default TextBlock Style-->
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gainsboro" />
</Style>
```

I want the foreground for all of my buttons to be different than the default TextBlock. I have my buttons laid out in my MVVM views similar to the following:

-- In myView.xaml

```
<Button Content="Scan" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Margin="10,0,0,10" Width="85" Foreground="Black" />
```

Sadly my button is not honoring the color I've explicitly set, it is still using the default TextBlock foreground color. Any thoughts on how I can get it to behave correctly? I've even tried setting TextBlock.Foreground on the button, but still no joy.

BTW, is there a best practice for setting foreground colors application wide? I was assuming my approach was acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all comes back to [`DependencyProperty` Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing). Unfortunately, since the `Button`'s `TextBlock` is generated by by the `ContentPresenter`, it doesn't explicitly set the `Foreground` property. It is inherited. Which is *way* down on the list. The good news is you can do it easily by explicitly setting a `TextBlock` as the `Content`:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Margin="9,0,0,9" Width="85">
    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="Scan" />
</Button>
```

For applying a global `Text` style, you have a couple of options. If you aren't creating your own theme, what you have done is pretty much your only option. However, if you are re-styling your controls, you can add a `Setter` with your default foreground. It is important to also set it on the default `Window` `Style` so things like `TextBlock` can inherit the value.

In a lot of cases, setting the `Window.Foreground` will give you most of what you want. However, some `Control`s explicitly set their `Foreground` in their default style, so they won't inherit your foreground.

Comment: Sweet, that did the trick. Knew it had something do DP dependency. Just wasn't thinking. I should have thought of that. Thanks!!!

Comment: Oh, as to my other question, is it standard practice to set default font properties across the board in a global resource dictionary?

Comment: @KyleLib I've updated the answer to give some hints for doing that.

Comment: Thanks, I eventually plan to implement themes, though I'm looking for a decent resource that describes using them.